# How are cookie values encoded?

Tags: javascript, front-end, cookies, encoding

Title kind of says it all. I can easily generate the md5 hash for the key, but I noticed in my devtools that the value is also encoded somehow. I tried setting it to the plain-text value, but this isn't being accepted by my password-protected pages. (It's a wp-postpass cookie I'm trying to set manually with frontend js). Thanks for any input.

Comment: encode data of cookie using php and then after store the data in cookie. when you retrieve the data you just need to encode using php.

Comment: even you can encode and decode using js too.

Comment: I don't understand, encode how? What kind of encoding?

Comment: in php : md5  and in js encode using base64 like atob() and btoa()  functions.

Comment: I'm sorry but i don't understand why it would be different in php or js. I thought the cookie would be the same regardless of which language is used to set it?

Comment: Here's the relevant code: [wp-login](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/5.0.2/wp-login.php#L478), [class-phppass](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/5.0.2/wp-includes/class-phpass.php#L36). At first glance it looks like it does eight iterations of MD5 with salt. So you can either try and replicate that, or you could try posting the password to a PHP endpoint you've added that could call this code and set the cookie for you?

Comment: Turns out there's already a JavaScript port of class-phpass: [node-phpass](https://github.com/jhurliman/node-phpass) ... except it rejects portableHashes = true, which is what wp_login uses. Oh well.

Comment: Thanks for your helpful comment! I guess I'll try to post the password to wp-login.php?action=postpass